Bound for entry-wise difference of p-unit vectors.
Suppose $p \in [1,2]$ and that $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{C}^3$ has $p$-norm equal to 1 (that is $|x|^p+|y|^p+|z|^p=1$). When $p=1$ or $p=2$ we get:
$$
|x-y|^p+|x-z|^p+|y-z|^p \leq 2^{p-1}+1.
$$
This bound is actually achieved by many unit vectors.
Question: Is this still true for any value of $p \in (1,2)$?
The best bound I can get is by interpolating the values at $1$ and $2$, which yields:
$$
|x-y|^p+|x-z|^p+|y-z|^p \leq \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^p.
$$
It can be checked  that for any $p \in (1,2)$
$$
 2^{p-1}+1 < \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^p,
$$
so the bound $ 2^{p-1}+1 $ would be a better one.
Thanks in advance.
